# newly installed applications not shown in Application menu or panel

Tags: 10.10, appmenu

I just installed some application called wmgtemp that shows live CPU temperatures via Synaptic Package Manager in Ubuntu 10.10. But I cannot find it in Application menu or Add to Panel. How can I find it to run? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Wmgtemp](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/man1/wmgtemp.1.html) is a tool for [Windows Maker](http://windowmaker.org/index.php) (this is another [X window manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_window_manager)) and uses lm_sensors to display CPU temperature. For Ubuntu the default window manager is [Metacity](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Metacity) or [Compiz](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompositeManager/ConfiguringCompiz).

Comment: Thanks! What is the default X window manager for Ubuntu 10.10?

Comment: Thanks! How to know what type of windows manager that my Ubuntu currently has?

Comment: @Tim: `gconftool -g /desktop/gnome/applications/window_manager/default`

Answer (score 0):

Hit <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, type `wmgtemp`, and hit run. Or run that same command on a terminal.